# how i can use if statment without else in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

i think that i have to put my question in different way.i wanna do this exactly as follows:
i used relu(x) function in keras layers, now i wanna change it and create my own activation function as follow:
1.create array as a look up table whose value between [-5,5] with 's' step (s=0.1) so my look up table should contain 102 numbers,e.g. [-5,-4.9...+4.9,5]
2.create Y array in shape of above lookup table.initial value of Y is zero, {Yi} are learnable parameters in training
3=calculated f(x)=1/s(yi(xi+1−x)+yi+1(x−xi)), if xi ≤ x ≤ xi+1 
 For any input value between xi and xi+1, the output is
 linearly interpolated from yi and yi+1,xi and xi+1 should be find in look up table and corresponding yi and yi+1 in Y
4=relu(f(x))
the problem is how can i write this activation function in keras?

Comment: I just noticed you have number as a tensor? I'd probably rename that to something less confusing and how are you trying to compare an element to a tensor? Are you wanting arrays of size number that have the logical indexing for where they are less than LT[i]?

Comment: You want `g.sort()` or `g = sorted(g)`; what you have now replaces the result with `None`.

Comment: @GrantWilliams thanks for your answer,i should create my own activation function so used custom function in keras and  'inputs' is tensor in  def call(),LT similar to lookup table,and i wanna take of two numbers of it, the one of this numbers grater than and another one shall be less than of input tensor

Comment: @chepner g.sort() run currently when number isnt tensor .that is not my broblem ,my problem is: a list which has two number should be find in there, the error will be apear : cant use tensor as bool_var , when i want to use "if" statment either the largest less number or smalest greater number of tensor otherwise may used 'tf.cond' statment then at last the "value error" apear when i used 'tf.no_op' on 'tf.cond' in the false statment.how can i solve this error ?

Comment: Maybe you could try to write clearly in your post what your end goal is.  You wrote something in the two comments above, but it's confusing.  My guess is that what you are trying to do is impossible in tf (but I don't quite understand what you are trying to do).  If you tell us more generally what you are trying to accomplish, maybe we could suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: @toto2 question edited plz check it

Answer (score 0):

If this is numpy just use logical indexing.

```
g = LT[LT > number]
l = LT[LT <= number]
```